# How do I mock a controller variable in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, controller, mocking

My index action will list the customers in database and I want to test the controller without the database dependency, so I need to mock the customers variable.

One way that I found was setting *customers* in the global scope:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var request, expect, app;


var customers = [
  { name : 'Customer A', email : "a@customer.com"},
  { name : 'Customer B', email : "b@customer.com"},
  { name : 'Customer C', email : "c@customer.com"},
  { name : 'Customer D', email : "d@customer.com"}
  ];

global.customers = customers;

request = require('supertest');
expect = require('expect.js');
app = require('../index');

describe('GET /api/customers', function(){

  it('should list the customers', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/api/customers')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        expect(res.body.length).to.be(4)
        done()
      });
  });

});
```

```
var _dataFromMyDatabase = [
  { name : 'Customer from Database', email : "database@customer.com"}
  ];

exports.index = function(req, res){
  var customers = global.customers || _dataFromMyDatabase;
  res.json(customers);
};
```

But I guess this is not the better way to do it, so I'm looking for any better idea. :)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Why not just create `_dataFromMyDatabase` statically in the test environment?

Comment: @EthanBrown but the _dataFromMyDatabase will be a function, ex: Customer.all(), and I don't want call this function during the test.

Comment: @Fabrício you can try to mock the request to "/api/customers" with nock: https://github.com/pgte/nock